# How to fire a dynamics c# plugin on specific field value

Tags: c#, dynamic, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming

How can I enable a dynamics c# plugin when a specific value is chosen from an options set?

For example: I have an option set that contains the values red, blue, and green. I want the plugin to start working when the user chooses blue and do nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The most granular you can get is to register a step to fire on the update message and filter to the option set field in question.

As far as checking the value and taking action (or no action for some values), your code has to handle that.

You can also register a pre-image to be able to tell what the value was prior to the change.